# Running appium test for android with multiple appPackage using @AndroidFindBy

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am in a process of changing the appPackage of my android apk from com.mycurrentpackage to com.myfuturepackage .

I have all the ids of the elements defined as

> com.mycurrentpackage:id/elementID

Currently I find the element as

> @AndroidFindBy(id = "com.mycurrentpackage:id/startup_text1")
>
> @CacheLookup
>
> private MobileElement startup_text1;

I want to be able to change it dynamically. So I defined a static variable appPackage.

Here is the part of the constructor

> ...
>
> appPackage = driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("appPackage").toString();
>
> PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(this.driver, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS), this);
>
> ...

As you can see appPackage is already defined before initializing elements.

But when I do it this way

> @AndroidFindBy(id = appPackage+":id/startup_text1")
>
> @CacheLookup
>
> private MobileElement startup_text1;

While compiling it says

> Error:(42, 35) java: attribute value must be constant

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of having package name as variable is correct, but it must be final:

```
public static final String appPackage = "com.mycurrentpackage";
```

Now you can use:

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = appPackage+":id/startup_text1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I also use

```
@AndroidFindBys({
@AndroidFindBy(id = "com.mycurrentpackage:id/startup_text1"),
@AndroidFindBy(id = "com.futurepackage:id/startup_text1")
})
@CacheLookup
private MobileElement startup_text1
```

When I used this one it takes a long time to load the page.

Do I need to list it as

```
private List<MobileElement> startup_text1
```